# How can I get the yellow box in tableofcontents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing an article with LaTeX and I'm wondering how to get this yellow boxes around the clickable elements of table of contents not just see the hand (mouse).

Comment: They're not always yellow. By default they're usually red frames, but you're probably talking about adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your document preamble. You can control the look of the elements, since all cross-referencing will follow suit (references to figures, tables as well as citations). More detail is available in the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html).

Comment: @Werner You should write down an answer of your comment.

Comment: actually if you try to view a table of contents with firefox pdf viewer by typing "firefox path_2_your_pdf" you will see the yellow boxes , but with evince or acroread it's not happening. Any idea?? and thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: I voted to close as this seems to be relevant to the viewer in use and is off-topic on this site.